# Sentinel-2 image size in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am interested in the spatial coverage of Sentinel-2 and noticed that for an image of size 10980x10980 px (á 10*10 m²), the computed area covered is not 12056.04 km² as expected, but 12052.267583 km². I also tried the establish a band with the resolution in m² and got 12043.810046 km².

This is the code:

```
// Load single image
var img = ee.Image("COPERNICUS/S2/20180613T000139_20180613T000140_T09XWL")

// Define native pixelArea band (100 m**2 for S-2 B2)
var nativePixelArea = img.select('B2')
                         .multiply(0)
                         .add(100)
                         .rename('nativePixelArea');
// Compute pixel area as new band
var computedPixelArea = img.select('B2')
                           .multiply(0)
                           .add(1)
                           .multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea())
                           .rename('computedPixelArea');

// Add bands to image.
img = ee.Image(img).addBands([nativePixelArea, computedPixelArea]);

print(img.select('computedPixelArea').reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), 
  geometry: img.geometry(),
  maxPixels: 1e12,
  scale: 10,
  }));

print(img.select('nativePixelArea').reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), 
  geometry: img.geometry(),
  maxPixels: 1e12,
  scale: 10,
  }));
```

Comment: How do you actually see the image size? When I run this (I am running the analagous code in Python), `img.select('nativePixelArea').reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), 
  geometry: img.geometry(),
  maxPixels: 1e12,
  scale: 10,
  })` returns a <class 'ee.dictionary.Dictionary'> and it's not clear to me how to get the actual image size.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I figured it out, will add my answer to the below.

Answer (score 2):

Copernicus images use a UTM (Universal Transverse Mercator) projection (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system). The units of this projection are almost, but not quite, true metres - they differ by up to 0.1%, which is in line with the different area calculations you're seeing, as each pixel's true area (ee.Image.pixelArea()) will be slightly different from its nominal area (100m^2).

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I came across this thread looking for a Python solution of how to extract computed Pixel Area of an image. Leaving this function here in case it's useful for anyone else:

```
def get_computed_pixel_area(image, band, bounds, scale):
    """
    Get Pixel Area of an Image and Band (in square KM)

    https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321456/sentinel-2-image-size-in-google-earth-engine
    """
    computedPixelArea = image.select(band)\
                             .multiply(0)\
                             .add(1)\
                             .multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea())\
                             .rename('computedPixelArea')
    image = ee.Image(image).addBands([computedPixelArea]);
    area = image.select('computedPixelArea').reduceRegion(reducer=ee.Reducer.sum(),
                                                          geometry=bounds,
                                                          maxPixels=1e12,
                                                          scale=scale)
    area_info = area.getInfo()
    return area_info['computedPixelArea']
```

One of the errors I was running into was

```
EEException: Image.reduceRegion: Provide 'geometry' parameter when aggregating over an unbounded image.
```

when I passed in

```
geometry=img.geometry(),
```

as the original post does. Instead I passed in a parameter, `bounds` which I manually defined using a `ee.Geometry.Rectangle` object.